# @JsonProperty is not applying for BeanWrapper

Tags: java, spring, jackson, objectmapper

In create flow ObjectMapper casting works fine (if "first_name" and "last_name" is passed). I am working on an update flow. I need to patch only the payload data to the existing DB Data.

**My POJO:**

```
public class Contact
{
    @JsonProperty( "first_name" )
    @JsonView( ContactViews.CommonFields.class )
    private String firstName;

    @JsonProperty( "last_name" )
    @JsonView( ContactViews.CommonFields.class )
    private String lastName;

    public String getFirstName()
        {
            return firstName;
        }

    public void setFirstName( String firstName )
        {       
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

    public String getLastName()
        {
            return lastName;
        }

    public void setLastName( String lastName )
        {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }
}
```

Say I have an existing contact only with "first_name". I need to update it with "last_name". I am receiving the payload ( {"last_name":"XYZ"} ) in the form of map. How do i update the existing contact with the payload Map.

**Existing code for create:**

```
 Contact contact = mapper.readerWithView( ContactViews.CommonFields.class ).forType( Contact.class ).readValue( mapper.writeValueAsString( payloadMap ) );
```

I tried with adding additional getters and setters. It was working fine. But I want to overcome this since there are lots of fields. Any help would be appreciated!!

Additional Getters & Setters (to make it work - but i need to avoid it):

```
    @JsonProperty( "first_name" )
    public String getFirst_name()
        {
            return firstName;
        }

    @JsonProperty( "first_name" )
    public void setFirst_name( String firstName )
        {       
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

    @JsonProperty( "last_name" )
    public String getLast_name()
        {
            return lastName;
        }

    @JsonProperty( "last_name" )
    public void setLast_name( String lastName )
        {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }
```

I am using this for other functions (But this doesnt work without the additional getters and setters):

```
public static void applyMapOntoInstance( Object instance , Map <String , ?> properties )
        {
            if ( Utilities.isEmpty( properties ) )
                return;

            String propertyName;

            BeanWrapper beanWrapper = PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess( instance );
            for ( Object name : properties.entrySet() )
                {
                    Map.Entry <String , ?> entry = (Map.Entry <String , ?>) name;
                    propertyName = entry.getKey();
                    if ( beanWrapper.isWritableProperty( propertyName ) )
                        beanWrapper.setPropertyValue( propertyName , entry.getValue() );
                }
        }

    public static void copyValues( Object source , Object target , Iterable <String> properties )
        {
            BeanWrapper src = new BeanWrapperImpl( source );
            BeanWrapper trg = new BeanWrapperImpl( target );

            for ( String propertyName : properties )
                trg.setPropertyValue( propertyName , src.getPropertyValue( propertyName ) );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty`

Comment: I am using that only